# How to import an update of Download Items into NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I'd like to update all of my download items with a value in a particular checkbox custitem_trw_commissionitem, but there doesn't seem to be any selection for download items using the CSV import tool. Is this not supported? If not, how else can it be accomplished?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

SuiteScript might be your only solution but I dont know of the top of my head if Download Items are scriptable.